# How can i find k-best solutions?

Tags: optimization, solver, ms-solver-foundation

I'm using Microsoft solver, and have wanted to ask how can i find

K-best solutions using LP and not just the optimal one?

I know that CPLEX has *solution pool* feature for
example.

Thank you for the help.

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [blog post](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-best-solutions.html) by Paul Rubin about finding k best solutions.